# Save entity with realtion

Tags: spring

I have two entities with one-to-mane relationship:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<RealEstate> realEstates = new ArrayList<>();
@Entity
public class RealEstate implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;
```

I try to save realEstate entity with this code:

```
realEstate.setUser(user);
    realEstateService.saveRealEstate(realEstate);
```

And this response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name" : "Bueno",
        "user" : 1
    }
]
```

By all I have is creating new record in user table and relation with this new ID.
What I do wrong? What I need to read about this?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to save ***User*** entity record and then ***RealEstate*** entity record.

Please read this article to implement One To Many relationship. I am sure your issue will be resolved.

https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-one-to-many-mapping